# Adding more data in the view using Symfony and Twig templating engine

Tags: php, api, symfony, twig

I am trying to add more data from API to my page. The API has been paginated due to memory concerns. I am using symfony and Twig templating to get a list of articles. The API call has filter of page number. Is there a way I can call this API multiple times in my display function to get the data from other pages.
Here is my code. In the controller I have the following display function

```
 public function display(Application $app)
    {
        $lang                = $app['filterLang'];
        $years               = [];
        $activeYear          = $this->getActiveYear($app['request']->get('year'));
        $modelManagerFactory = $app['factories.model_manager'];

        $articleCmsManager = $modelManagerFactory->create('ArticleManager');
        $articles          = $articleCmsManager->getList($lang, $activeYear);
        $categories        = $articleCmsManager->getCategories();
        $cmsYears          = $articleCmsManager->getCmsYears($lang);
        $allYears          = array_unique(array_merge($years, $cmsYears));
        $oldActiveYear     = $activeYear;

        if (is_null($app['request']->get('year')) && empty($articles)) {
            $activeYear = $oldActiveYear - 1;
            $articles   = $articleCmsManager->getList($lang, $activeYear);
        }

        $articleIssues = [];
        foreach ($articles as $article) {
            if (strpos($article->publicationDate, "$activeYear") !== false) {
                $category = [
                    'en_US' => isset($categories['en_US'][$article->category]) ? $categories['en_US'][$article->category] : ''
                ];

                if ('en_US' != $lang) {
                    $category[$lang] = isset($categories[$lang][$article->category]) ? $categories[$lang][$article->category] : '';
                }

                $articleIssues[] = [
                    'title' => isset($article->content->title) ? $article->content->title : '',
                    'category' => $category,
                    'image' => isset($article->image) ? $article->image : '',
                    'url' => isset($article->content->url) ? $article->content->url : '',
                    'date' => isset($article->publicationDate) ? $article->publicationDate : '',
                    'artist' => isset($article->artist) ? $article->artist : '',
                    'metadescription' => isset($article->content->metadescription) ? $article->content->metadescription : ''
                ];
            }
        }

        return $app['twig']->render(
            'archive/ArchivePage.html',
            array(
                'issues' => [],
                'articles' => $articleIssues,
                'years' => $allYears,
                'activeYear' => $activeYear
            )
        );
    }
```

The getList function which is responsible for the getting the data from the API is defined as

```
public function getList($lang = null, $activeYear = null)
    {
        // define a fallback language (locale)

        $fallbackLang = '';
        $filter = [
            'filter[sort]=startdate_desc',
            'page=0',
            'per_page=100',
            'filter[status]=published',
            'filter[publicationDate]='.urlencode(date("Y-m-d H:i:s")),
            'filter[year]='.$activeYear
        ];

        $query = array(
            'url' => '/cms/article?'.implode('&', $filter),
            'data' => array()
        );

        $results = $this->repo->getList($query);

        $articles = array();
        foreach ($results as $article) {
            if (!empty($article->displayInArchive)) {
                if (isset($article->content->$lang->html) && !empty($article->content->$lang->html)) {
                    $article->content = $article->content->$lang;
                    $articles[] = $article;
                } elseif (isset($article->content->$fallbackLang->html) && !empty($article->content->$fallbackLang->html)) {
                    $article->content = $article->content->$fallbackLang;
                    $articles[] = $article;
                }
            }
        }

        return $articles;
    }
```

As you can see the view can only get a total of 100 results i.e all the articles on page 0. Now if I also want to show the articles on page 1,2 and so on the same view i.e archive how do I go about doing that without running into memory constraints.

Comment: Just use doctrine pagination.

Comment: The API already supports pagination via the filter, I need to add the data from page 1,2,3 and so on.

Comment: Why don't you modify your `getList` function to take in the page and limit as parameters and add them to your filter?